# Shiurim with transcription

Tags: hebrew, english, adult-learning

Occasionally, I encountered difficulties comprehending the intricate nuances of certain accents, resulting in the partial loss of content. As of late, I have been perusing episodes presented by Rabbi Mansour's Daily Halacha, accompanied by comprehensive transcriptions. I would greatly appreciate any other resources with transcription (English or Hebrew), irrespective of tradition, that you may suggest.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Mello and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!